# Listing folders but exclude if folder matched from listing in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am playing around with Bash for the first time.

This script will list all folders, however I want to modify it to not list a certain folder if possible.

Working:

```
_list_banners () {
  for f in * ; do [ -d "$f" ] && echo ${_handle_banner_type}${_handle_message} $f ; done
}
```

This works and lists the folders, but I want to exclude for example folder `MASTER` from the list.

Attempted:

```
_list_banners () {
  for f in * ;
    if [ $f != "MASTER" ]; then
      do [ -d "$f" ] && echo ${_handle_banner_type}${_handle_message} $f
    fi
  ; done
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following error instead of my file list:

```
$ bash myscript
myscript: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
myscript: line 3: `    if [ $f != "MASTER" ]; then'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move both the directory check and the exclusion into your glob (requires [`shopt -s extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), and [`shopt -s nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) would be a good idea to avoid unexpected behaviour when nothing matches):

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob

_list_banners () {
    for f in !(MASTER)/; do 
        echo "${_handle_banner_type}${_handle_message} $f"
    done
}
```

`!(MASTER)` is a glob that excludes `MASTER`, and appending `/` only returns directories.

If you want just the directory name without the trailing slash, you can use `${f%/}` instead of just `$f` on the `echo` line.

Comment: ./build.sh: line 73: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./build.sh: line 73: `  for f in !(MASTER)/; do'

Comment: @James Did you set `shopt -s extglob`? And are you running Bash, and not POSIX sh?

Comment: @James I've added the shell option commands. They just have to be somewhere in your script if you want them.

Comment: yea working good now thanks mate, is there a way to remove the trailing / at the end of the folders?

Comment: @James I've added how to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`do` is part of the for loop and shouldn't be moved inside the `if` block:

```
_list_banners () {
  for f in * ;
  do 
    if [ "$f" != "MASTER" ]; then
      [ -d "$f" ] && echo "${_handle_banner_type}${_handle_message} $f"
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helping hand, however, i get this ./build.sh: line 75: [: too many arguments which is the if condition line... any ideas?

Comment: This happens when `$f` is not quoted and you have a filename that contains a space or glob character. I've added additional quoting