Dynamically include specific directories and exclude others in Bash select
I'm working on a series of bash scripts to automate directory and file creation in a project. I have a limited working proficiency in shell scripts.
This is the basic project directory structure:
->
--> applications/
----> sub_dir1/
--> classes/
----> sub_dir1/
------> file1
------> file2
----> sub_dir2/
----> sub_dir3/
----> sub_dir4/

Currently, my script navigates to classes/ and executes this catchall select code, which I cribbed from here.
select d in */; do
  test -n "$d" && break
  echo ">>> Invalid Selection"
done

This dynamically lists ALL of the sub-directories under classes/, as expected. If I add sub_dir5/ under classes/ and rerun the script with this code snippet, sub_dir5/ is populated, which is what I want...
...except there is a static group of sub-directories that I would like to exclude from this select, while preserving the functionality of dynamically generating newly added sub-directories.
I've tried creating an array of the static directories to exclude (e.g. directoriesToExclude=("sub_dir2" "sub_dir4"), but I don't know how to incorporate that variable into the select above. I've looked at examples using find and prune and not, various loops, and various conditionals, and I can't figure it out...
Helpfully (or maybe not), there are seven sub-directories with the same prefix (e.g thing-*) that I'd like to exclude, along with three other sub-directories that do not share that prefix. I know there is a way to lump directories/files with the same naming convention together, but again, I'm at a loss.

Edit 4/25/2024 (more robust solution)
For anyone who might stumble upon this question in the future, here is how this shook out ultimately.
# Start script
cd classes/

PS3="Which directory should this class be initialized in? Enter the corresponding number. "
shopt -s extglob

# START FILTER LOGIC
# assign all directories in classes/ to dirs array
dirs=(./*)
# find all directories with a package.json file one-level deep in dirs array
files=($(find . "${dirs[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -name "package.json"))
# remove package.json suffixes from identified directories
exclude=("${files[@]%%/"package.json"}")

dirsToPrint=()

# build new array of directories that are not in the exclude array
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  if ! [[ "${exclude[@]}" =~ "${dir}" ]]; then
    dirsToPrint+=("${dir}")
  fi
done

# display directories to print in user select list
select subdir in "${dirsToPrint[@]}"; do
  test -n "$subdir" && break
  echo ">>> Invalid Selection"
done
# END FILTER LOGIC
# Other logic continues from here

This will allow my team to dynamically display any existing and new directories that do not have a package.json file nested directly in them, as those directories are standalone and will not have any future subdirectories added to them.
Again, thanks for your help!

Adapting the glob pattern from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632533/9952196 should get you most of the way there.

bravo using the underappreciated select feature even though you "have a limited working proficiency in shell scripts". You'll probably like case ; esac as well. Good luck.

Thank you for your engagement on this post, I appreciate it!

Use an extglob:
shopt -s extglob
select d in !(sub_dir2|sub_dir4)/; do
...


This worked great, thank you! In implementing this, I realized that I can probably make even the excluded directories list dynamic because the directories I want to exclude have a lib folder nested directly in them, whereas the directories to include just have other directories underneath them...so I'll figure out how to exclude by that parameter. I appreciate your help!

To exclude specific sub-directories from your select loop, you can modify your code to filter out the directories you want to exclude. I’ll provide you with an example of how to achieve this.
First, let’s create an array containing the static directories you want to exclude. You mentioned that there are seven sub-directories with the same prefix (e.g., thing-*) and three other sub-directories that do not share that prefix. We’ll use this information to construct our exclusion list.
#!/bin/bash  
# Define the static directories to exclude

declare -a directoriesToExclude=("sub_dir2" "sub_dir4" "thing-1" "thing-2" "thing-3" "thing-4" "thing-5" "thing-6" "thing-7")

# Dynamically list all sub-directories under classes/
select d in */; do
  # Check if the selected directory is non-empty and not in the exclusion list
  if [[ -n "$d" && ! " ${directoriesToExclude[@]} " =~ " $d " ]]; then
    break
  else
    echo ">>> Invalid Selection"
  fi
done

# Now you can use the selected directory ($d) for further processing
echo "Selected directory: $d"


OP wants to remove certain directories so they don't show up in the select prompt.

Was any of this AI-generated?
